# Power Bi Report Server Sharepoint Online list scheduled refresh

Tags: powerbi, sharepoint-list, power-bi-report-server

I am using the Power Bi Report Server to create a report that uses the Sharepoint Online List. Has anyone figured out some way or a workaround where we can use a Sharepoint Online List and create a scheduled refresh? I have tried importing that data into an Excel file on Sharepoint and also tried to import it from CSV file that gets the update using Flows, but I can't find a way where we can have scheduled refresh. Is there any other way apart from but the data from that list in excel file on a shared directory?
Any ideas would be appreciated.